# たら as an emotional suffix

Tags: suffixes

In this phrase I couldn't find another meaning of たら (I guess it's not -た＋ら）:

> **自分たら**の事しか考えてなかった

I'd translate it as "I think only of my own business" or "I think only of myself".

I found in [Denshi jisho](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89&eng=&dict=edict) that たら　attached to someone name is used to express exasperation. What would a good way to translate this "exasperation" in English?

What about other particles like な,　that would possibly be misunderstood?

Comment: def 2 at http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89&dtype=3&dname=2ss&stype=0&index=145110&pagenum=1 and def 3 at http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&index=02634800&pagenum=1 has a couple of examples

Comment: Did you hear it or read it? I have no idea about such a usage of たら.

Comment: It's often used when exasperated: "じゃ、お前は上手だと言ってるから、自分でやってみ[たら]!" :P

Answer (score 5):

I think that it is simply a typo for “自分たちの,” unless it is a dialectal vocabulary which I am not aware of.

The usage to indicate exasperation which you mentioned in the question probably refers to [the たら which was originally といったら](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=112293400000&pagenum=1), but たら in your example cannot be this word because this word cannot be followed by case particles such as の.

Comment: I see, I've read it in written text. It doesn't seem to be a typo because the character repeats it at last two times in two different pages.